# unknown column 'X' in field list

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, insert-into

I want to add a line into mysql via php.

In short, the code looks like:

```
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['email']);

        $token = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));


            $mysqli->query('SET NAMES utf8');

            $insertsignup = "INSERT INTO `betasignup`(`signupDate`, `email`, `token`, `activated`) SELECT CURDATE(), '" . $email . "', '" . $token . "', 'N';";
            echo $insertsignup;

            $insert = $mysqli->query($insertsignup) or          
                die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
```

the "echo" was inserted to debug the query.

Output:

> INSERT INTO `betasignup`(`signupDate`, `email`, `token`, `activated`) SELECT CURDATE(), 'username@email.com', '58d15fe49629b3942a58acfb64a0cb07', 'N';

followed by:

> Unknown column 'token' in 'field list'

Here is the table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `betasignup` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `signupDate` date NOT NULL,
  `email` text NOT NULL,
  `token` text NOT NULL,
  `activated` enum('Y','N') NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

The Query works perfectly when inserted into phpmyadmin or mysql-commandline.

On localhost dev-environment it works, in live (web) not.

Any ideas?

Comment: Because there's no `token` field on prod?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your production database is probably not similar as the one in your dev environment? It is apparently missing the 'token' field live.

Comment: i added the database structure of prod. field 'token' is available and the query works in phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0):

Found it:

just moved the whole thing from webhoster to own rootserver and did not update my brain...

database was also moved to rootserver. phpmyadmin was still webhost...

of course column 'token' WAS missing.

thanks!